# "Sacred cow" idiom explanation

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, expressions

There's an idiom in the English language called "Sacred cow" which means 'immunity from criticism or opposition'. I am not sure about the proper use of it in the contexts like these:

> "I can't guarantee that this argument is a **sacred cow**, but in my opinion, the origin of humanity is Mars".

Or:

> "If a person drinks and smokes a lot, he will become old very quickly, but this statement is not a **sacred cow**, sometimes you see the opposite situation, but very rarely".

The problem is that in the Russian language, you may use the idiom **"the truth in its last instance/authority"** *(rus. "Истина в последней инстанции")*. That's why the aforesaid sentences would look like:

> "I can't guarantee that this argument is **the truth in its last instance/authority**, but in my opinion, the origin of humanity is Mars" - *(rus. "Я не гарантирую истину в последней инстанции, но по-моему мнению, люди произошли с Марса")*

> "If a person drinks and smokes a lot, he will become old very quickly, but this statement is not **the truth in its last instance/authority**, sometimes you see the opposite situation, but very rarely" - *(rus. "Если человек много пьет и курит, то он очень быстро состарится, но это утверждение не является истиной в последней инстанции, иногда можно увидеть обратную ситуацию, но это редкость")*.

So, the question is, how can I properly translate this "the truth in its last instance/authority" idiom, and is it completely comprehensible and useful in English too?

It's important to mention that I don't accept any compromises like saying "human" instead of "person" (in Russian, saying 'person' instead of 'human' sounds odd, not vice versa like in English) - yes, English speakers will understand the meaning, but that would sound funny and inappropriate. Same here, if the sentence "the truth in its last instance/authority" sounds unnatural, I need to know that for sure.

Comment: Based on research in several dictionaries, I have not been able to find an argument referenced as a "sacred cow". Instead, it seems like "sacred cow" refers to an idea, concept, or person that everyone blindly supports without thinking or believes to be above scrutiny.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of "sacred cow" isn't idiomatic.

A sacred cow is some principle that a person or group considers immune from criticism  *but unreasonably so*.

It is almost always used to criticise the very opinion that the person considers to be a sacred cow!

> The free market has become the sacred cow of conservative politicians, even as it plunges us into climate disaster.

You don't say that a statement is a "sacred cow".  You could say

> That smoking is harmful to health has become a sacred cow of the medical profession...

But you would then go on to explain why smoking has a number of health benefits.

I think the expression you want is "the final word"

> I can't guarantee that this is my final word on the matter, but in my opinion, the origin of humanity is Mars

Or "not without exceptions"

> If a person drinks and smokes a lot, he will become old very quickly, but this statement is not without exceptions; sometimes you see the opposite situation, but very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

“Sacred cow” is actually a critical statement. Its origin is British contempt for the Hindu belief in the divinity of bovines. A “sacred cow” is something that cannot be attacked because it is a matter of faith rather than reasoned argument.

I think the phrases that you are looking for are “not absolutely true” and “not necessarily true.” These two phrases have different meanings.

> People who drink and smoke a lot become old very quickly, but this is not absolutely true because there are rare exceptions.

This is an assertion that something is usually true, but not always true.

> In my opinion, life began on Mars, but this is not necessarily true.

The meaning here is that the statement can **NOT** be proved the way a mathematical theorem can be proved.

I do not know Russian at all so I may be missing some nuance, but “sacred cow” is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I found that suggestion of the Russian-English dictionary pretty doubtful too, but couldn't find any appropriate explanation nor analog. That's why I was thinking about idiomatic construction that may be used in this context if it's possible of course. For sure, I know how to rephrase the whole text in order to avoid using aforesaid Russian idiom (or its adaptation), but this won't be interesting, that's the point.

Comment: I think both my answer and that of James K give you decent options that will express your meaning in idiomatic English.